# How can I produce a value while querying data from a range in Google Sheets?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, match, google-query-language

How can I have the first column automatically populated with specific values on each query of the formula?

This is the formula I had started with: `={"COGS",query(Sheet30!A2:D,"select * ")}`, thinking that COGS would be in the rows below, but if I have more than one row in the range `POs!J2:V`, it already throws an error.

This is how it should look like:
[image]

[Here is a sheet for test](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oRHrPhT6XlCPwWscmMrTJh8Ya8hs_dKX-Op4ThyiQJQ/edit?usp=sharing), in case you you feel like it.

Comment: Make sure to add input and expected output as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE/LINK) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). Your table should be a [mre].[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with `but if I have more than one row in the range POs!J2:V, it already throws an error.`? What error do you get? Also, I don't see that sheet you're referring to: `POs!J2:V`. Please include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=QUERY({
 QUERY(Sheet30!A2:D, "select 'COGS',A,B,C,D label 'COGS''Type'", 1);
 QUERY(Sheet30!A3:D, "select 'Expenses',A,B,C,D label 'Expenses'''", 0)}, 
 "where Col2 is not null", 1)
```

[image]